# Disable only unwanted inputs Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have this cool piece of Javascript that disables rows and change color were input is disabled.

But I need:
If filled input #1 all other 3 inputs are disabled,
if filled input #3 all other 3 inputs are disabled, 
if filled input #2 and/or #4 then inputs #1 AND #3 are disabled.
Data is coming from database.

Javascript:

```
$(".input").on("keypress change keyup",function(){
   if($(this).val() != "")
   {
     $(this).parent().parent().find(".input").not($(this)).prop("disabled",true).css("background-color","#cccccc");  
   }
   else
   {         $(this).parent().parent().find(".input").prop("disabled",false).css("background-color","#ffffff");
   }
});
```

And here is the table code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

<sub><sup>This piece of code was made by  [Alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5168153/alexis).</sup></sub>

Comment: first thing to do is swap the IDs for Classes

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id. Big no no.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i was trying many codes so pasted wrong table :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the codes you seek...

#### HTML

To avoid the issue you were having with hidden inputs etc and not knowing the nth-term of each element, use classes instead:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input toggle all" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input toggle every-other" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input toggle all" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input toggle every-other" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### JQuery

```
$('body').on( 'keyup blur', '.input.toggle', function() {
    var $this = $( this );
    var $parent = $this.parent();
    var $disable = $parent.siblings().children();
    if ( $this.val() != "" )
    {
              if ( $this.is( '.all' ) )
                {
                      $disable = $parent.siblings().children( '.toggle' );
                }
              else if ( $this.is( '.every-other' ) )
                {
                      $disable = $parent.siblings().children( '.all' );
                }
              $disable.attr( 'disabled', true ).css("background-color","#ccc");
    }
    else
    {
        $disable.removeAttr('disabled').css("background-color","#fff");
    }
});
```

And [here](http://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/kkjxrm) is an example of it working.

Comment: Hmm this is close but color seems not to be showing anymore and it allows edits 1st and 3d but needed 2 and 4

Comment: if 1 or 3 then all others are disabled, if 2 or 4 the 1 and 3 are disabled right? colours added

Comment: i need 1 and 3 just to be disabled if user enters in tad 2 also now result is not instant :(

Comment: Cool works :) but If entered input #1 all other 3(#2 #3 #4) inputs are disabled,
if entered input #3 all other 3(#1 #2 #4) inputs are disabled, 
if entered input #2 and/or #4 then inputs #1 AND #3 are disabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125714/discussion-between-alexander-holman-and-ingus-graholskis).